# Angular6: Using Star Rating Component Multiple Places On A Single Page

Tags: html, angular

I am using star rating component in my AngularJS application. The issue I am facing is very simple. My form is dynamic and based on the type of input I generate the form. I have used rating component from [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/Qi6tEdIyaRoGgSj2z4M9/). This is working fine. The problem is in the example, the question are generated at one time. This is generated using array of items. My issue is I don't want to show all the rating based question at once. For example, question 1 could have response type 'text', question 2 could be rating, question 3 could be radio button and again question 4 could be rating. Code I use to generate my form is:

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <!-- Questions having no parent questions: -->
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'textBox'">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black" for={{question.id}}>{{question.question}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" placeholder={{question.placeholder}} [(ngModel)]="model[question.id]"
        name={{question.id}}>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'checkbox'">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black">{{question.question}}</label>
      <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
        <label class="control-label black" for={{option}}>{{option}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="" data-toggle="tooltip" name={{option}} [(ngModel)]="model[question.id][option]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'starRating'">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black">{{question.question}}</label>
      <div>
        <app-rating [rating]='item.rating' [itemId]='item.id' (ratingClick)='ratingComponentClick($event)'></app-rating>
     
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like Angular (based on title, Angular 6) and NOT AngularJS, is that correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You don't want to show all the questions of type `starRating` at once? What do you want to show? Are you looking to filter out certain question types?

Comment: @MichaelLynch: Yes, it is Angular6.

Comment: @MichaelKucinski I do want to show all the questions of type starRating. The issue is if you visit the above example, the array has all the questions and all the questions are shown at once(Maybe 5). My requirement is to use the said component 5 times for 5 questions scattered all over the form(starRating type questions are not sequential). There can be a questions of type input text, radio, starRating and they can be multiple with no defined order. Hope you understand this now.

Comment: @astm1982 I think I understand your requirement now. Give me a few minutes to write a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that you wish to use the snippet you shared above multiple times in the same form to render a series of "question" objects. However, because the snippet contains an `*ngFor`, it iterates over all the questions at once. To remedy this, I would introduce a `<app-question/>` component to render an individual question

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './question.component.css' ]
})
export class QuestionComponent  {
  @Input()
  model: any//the model to bind to
  @Input()
  question: any// the question object to read

  ratingComponentClick($event){
    this.model[this.question.id] = $event.rating;//somehow map the value to the model
  }

}
```

question.component.html:

```html
<!-- Questions having no parent questions: -->
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'textBox'">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black" for={{question.id}}>{{question.question}}</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" placeholder={{question.placeholder}} [(ngModel)]="model[question.id]"
    name={{question.id}}>
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'checkbox'">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black">{{question.question}}</label>
  <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
    <label class="control-label black" for={{option}}>{{option}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" data-toggle="tooltip" name={{option}} [(ngModel)]="model[question.id][option]">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="question.inputtype === 'starRating'">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4  black">{{question.question}}</label>
  <div>
    <app-rating [rating]='question.rating' [itemId]='question.id' (ratingClick)='ratingComponentClick($event)'></app-rating>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then use this new component as many times as you want and wherever you want:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myModel = {}
  questions = [
    { id: 'question1', rating: 3, question: 'Rate Angular', inputtype: 'starRating' },
    { id: 'question2', question: 'Does this answer your question?', inputtype: 'textBox' },
    { id: 'question3', rating: 1, question: 'Rate my answer', inputtype: 'starRating' }
  ];
}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<h1>Reusable Question Component</h1>
<app-question [model]="myModel" [question]="questions[0]"></app-question> 
<br>
<label>Here's another input</label>
<input type="text" name="myInput" [(ngModel)]="myModel.myInput">
<br>
<app-question [model]="myModel" [question]="questions[1]"></app-question> 
<br>
<app-question [model]="myModel" [question]="questions[2]"></app-question> 
<h2>Edit form to change model:</h2>
<pre>
  {{myModel | json}}
</pre>
```

[Here's a working version of the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmn4kf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). The main takeaway here is the separation of responsibilities: there is one component which contains the questions, and another which renders a single question. **However, this is not an optimal solution** because it does not adequately give you control over form validation. A better solution would to be to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) because they are designed for this very use case. Angular's official documentation has a tutorial worth reading [covering your very same use case](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form). Unfortunately, I feel that covering those topics would be out of the scope of this question, so if you have any further questions about reaction forms, please use the search or ask another question. I hope this helps!

P.S. I changed the `rating.component.css` to handle clearing the floats:

```css
:host::after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```